# Bot for "WordPress"

Tags: feature-request

With much edit experiences, I've seen a common mistake by all the newbie is typing **"WordPress"** as **"Wordpress"** or **"wordpress"**.

Is it feasible that we have a ***bot account*** to correct only the mistakes in the spelling of "WordPress".

**Disclaimer:** I know in a site of code, and bugs it's not mandatory to type the name of a program or CMS in a right way. It's just a thought.

Comment: See http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96/should-we-ask-for-reasonable-consistency-in-style-for-things-like-wordpress-v

Comment: Thanks @toscho.

Comment: Personally I don't care about trademarks. Its fine for me as far as it make sense. Doesn't matter if its `wp`, `WP`, `wordpress`, `Wordpress` or `WordPress` :)

Answer (score 5):

Auto-correction is difficult and error prone. What should that do with the string `wordpress` when it is part of a code fragment – just without proper indentation?

And *Wordpress* with a lower case *p* could be a statement, not an error. We have suggested edits and a review queue. Humans can judge these cases better than any software. I think we should not change user input automatically.

Comment: "Wordpress" inside a code fragment would be excluded by simply a `<pre>` or `<code>` tag. We will let the bot change all but the texts inside the `<pre>...</pre>` and/or `<code>...</code>` tag.

Comment: Many new users post code without proper formatting. Impossible to detect.

Comment: Yes, you are right.